# Is it possible to have a logical control add more than one root-level visual control?

Tags: wpf, layout, custom-controls, children

Simple question.  Say I create a custom control called `LabeledValue` which has 'Label' and  'Value' string properties.  What I'm wondering is if it's possible to have that control output two root-level visuals--say two TextBlocks--to the Visual Tree, or do they have to share a parent control?

Consider the case of placing this control logically on a grid.  I want the grid to have two visual children of type TextBlock which come pre-configured with Grid.Row set to '0' and '1' respectively.

```
// For this *LOGICAL* tree (i.e. what I type in XAML)...
<Grid>
    <LabeledValue Label="FooText" Value="FooValue" Grid.Row="0" />
    <LabeledValue Label="LaaText" Value="LaaValue" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>

// ...I want it to generate this *VISUAL* tree (XAML for hierarchical illustration only here)...
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="FooText"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="FooValue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock Text="LaaText"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="LaaValue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>

// ...and NOT this *VISUAL* tree. (XAML for hierarchical illustration only here)...
<Grid>
    <LabeledValue>
        <TextBlock Text="FooText"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="FooValue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    </LabeledValue>
    <LabeledValue>
        <TextBlock Text="LaaText"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="LaaValue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    </LabeledValue>
</Grid>
```

Hope that makes sense.

Note: This is a complete over-simplification of what we're actually doing, but if this can be answered/achieved, then it will show me what I need.

Comment: Interesting question, but why would one want that?

Comment: Because sometimes we don't want a single visual to represent the control  We want our to manage multiple root visuals directly.

I believe the markup extension below may be the way to go however.  Hadn't considered that.  I keep forgetting about those guys!  Gotta try it before I say yes for sure though.

Comment: I understand that you don't want a single root visual representing your control. But I would like to understand the advantages of this...

Comment: Please see the question.  It is explained there.

Comment: Valid reason. I did miss the parts with the grid rows when reading the question for the first time few days ago.

Comment: @Spontifixus, did you ever give this more thought?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  You would have to write a MarkupExtension (or maybe just a plain DependencyObject) that finds its parent Panel and inserts new elements based on its own position in the logical tree.  Maybe then you even remove yourself from the visual/logical tree.

Comment: Interesting concept to use the markup extensions.  Not quite sure that will work, but it will be fun to play with.  If it works, I'll mark yours as accepted.